# Java String to JSON conversion

Tags: java, json, web-services

i am getting data from restful api in String variable now i want to convert to JSON object but i am having problem while conversion it throws exception .Here is my code :

```
URL url = new URL("SOME URL");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream())));

String output;
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}

conn.disconnect();


JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(output);
String projecname=(String) jObject.get("name");
System.out.print(projecname);
```

MY string contain

```
 {"data":{"name":"New Product","id":1,"description":"","is_active":true,"parent":{"id":0,"name":"All Projects"}}}
```

this is the string which i want in json but it shows me Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.<init>(JSONTokener.java:83)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:310)
    at Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `name` is present inside the `data`. You need to parse a JSON hierarchically to be able to fetch the data properly.

```
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(output); // json
JSONObject data = jObject.getJSONObject("data"); // get data object
String projectname = data.getString("name"); // get the name from data.
```

Note: This example uses the `org.json.JSONObject` class and not `org.json.simple.JSONObject`.

---

As "Matthew" mentioned in the comments that he is using `org.json.simple.JSONObject`, I'm adding my comment details in the answer.

> Try to use the `org.json.JSONObject` instead. But then if you can't change your JSON library, you can [refer to this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) which uses the same library as yours and check the how to read a json part from it.

Sample from the link provided:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
```

Comment: My `org.json.simple.JSONObject` does not have a constructor for String, only a default contructor and one that takes a Map?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen - Try to use the [`org.json.JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) instead. But then if you can't change your JSON library, you can refer [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) which uses the same library as yours and check the how to read a json part from it. Should be fairly useful to you :)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting NullPointerException as the "output" is null when the while loop ends. You can collect the output in some buffer and then use it, something like this-

```
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
        buffer.append(output);
    }
    output = buffer.toString(); // now you have the output
    conn.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting the String to JsonNode using ObjectMapper object :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// For text string
JsonNode = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString("Text-string"), JsonNode.class)

// For Array String
JsonNode = mapper.readValue("[\"Text-Array\"]"), JsonNode.class)

// For Json String 
String json = "{\"id\" : \"1\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();
JsonParser jsonParser = factory.createParser(json);
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonParser);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of JSONObject , you can use ObjectMapper to convert java object to json string

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String requestBean = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourObject);
```

Comment: Question is about converting Java String to JSON and not vice-versa

Comment: It will give data with slash (java string). Not a proper Json format [{\"date\":\"2020-01-03\"}].