# how to convert String to JSONObject in android studio

Tags: android

How to fix this error in my logcat...

> org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

[image]

Comment: show me your string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String to JSON conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070382/java-string-to-json-conversion)

Comment: Your data return ... HTML format, it 's not JSON format. You must be sure your data reuturn JSON. Maybe your request is not correct.

Comment: I fix my first error and now my error is JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Answer (score 2):

your string which is logged in the clip is in HTML format, not JSON.

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
try {
     jobj = new JSONObject(string);
} catch (JSONException e) {
     //e.printStackTrace();
}
```

will give you a json object if your input is in correct json format

Comment: I fix my first error and now my error is JSONException: End of input at character 0.

Comment: that usually means empty/null string was parsed, show the string you're passing now

Answer (score 1):

```
try {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(YOUR_STRING);
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I fix my first error and now my error is JSONException: End of input at character 0.